# AttributeError on everything with Greppo in JupyterLab

Tags: python, attributes, dashboard, jupyter-lab

I am trying to create a dashboard using Greppo in JupyterLab, but whatever I try to do following the documentation gives me an AttributeError:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/kt/ttp65kq11zdgh8vfjd7dtgm40000gn/T/ipykernel_83794/915093404.py in <module>
----> 1 app.base_layer(
      2     name="CartoDB Light",
      3     visible=True,
      4     url="https://cartodb-basemaps-a.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png",
      5     subdomains=None,

AttributeError: 'GreppoApp' object has no attribute 'base_layer'
```

And:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/kt/ttp65kq11zdgh8vfjd7dtgm40000gn/T/ipykernel_83794/1068074614.py in <module>
      5 }
      6 
----> 7 app.vector_layer(
      8     data = iceye_breaks,
      9     name = 'Flood',

AttributeError: 'GreppoApp' object has no attribute 'vector_layer'
```

I installed Greppo on a MacBook using: "pip install greppo". Here is a sample of my code that gives the errors:

```
from greppo import app

app.base_layer(
    name="CartoDB Light",
    visible=True,
    url="https://cartodb-basemaps-a.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png",
    subdomains=None,
    attribution='&copy; <a target="_blank" href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
)

app.base_layer(
    provider = "CartoDB Positron"
)

choropleth_style = {
    'key_on': 'flood_class', 
    'bins': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'palette': 'Blues',
}

app.vector_layer(
    data = iceye_breaks,
    name = 'Flood',
    description = 'Flood depths monitored by ICEYE',
    style = {'choropleth': choropleth_style},
)

app.vector_layer(
    data = sos_build,
    name = 'Severly inundated buildings',
    description = 'Buildings inundated by at least 0.5m of floodwater.',
    style = {"color": "#e41a1c"},
    visible = True
)
```

Google or StackOverFlow didn't give any results regarding this problem and all instructions and tutorials point to me doing everything right. I even tried terminating the kernel and restarting JupyterLab.

Comment: You're most likely not running the application properly: [Greppo Quickstart - Run App](https://docs.greppo.io/quickstart.html#run-app)

Comment: @matszwecja still not working I get an "invalid syntax" error when trying to run "touch app.py"

Comment: Because that's not Python statement, that is command line command. Do you really have to be using JupyterLab?